# Groovy equivalent to OCL forAll

Tags: groovy, ocl

What is the Groovy equivalent to the forAll method in OCL?

---

Let's say that I have a list of items.

```
def items = new LinkedList<Item>();
```

What is the Groovy way to express a predicate that holds if and only if all items match a certain criteria?

---

The following code snippet does not work, because the inner return only jumps out of the current iteration of the each closure, not out of the forAll method.

```
boolean forAll(def items)
{
    items.each { item -> if (!item.matchesCriteria()) return false; };
    return true;
}
```

---

The following code snippet, which should do the trick, feels cumbersome and not Groovy-like.

```
boolean forAll(def items)
{
    boolean acceptable = true;
    items.each { item -> if (!item.matchesCriteria()) acceptable = false; };
    return acceptable;
}
```

---

I am looking for a way to lazily evaluate the predicate, so that the evaluation would finish when a first non-matching item is found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [every](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#every%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)

```
items.every { it.matchesCriteria() }
```

Answer (score 3):

In groovy that's very easy:

```
def yourCollection = [0,1,"", "sunshine", true,false]

assert yourCollection.any() // If any element is true
```

or if you want to make sure, all are true

```
assert !yourCollection.every()
```

you can even do it with a closure

```
assert yourCollection.any { it == "sunshine" } // matches one element, and returns true
```

or

```
assert !yourCollection.every { it == "sunshine" } // does not match all elements
```